# How to not trigger the pipeline after a push inside a pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, push, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working with files inside a GitLab CI/CD pipeline and push them in the repository at the end of the job.

The problem is that the push itself trigger the run of the pipeline.

I tried to solve this issue by adding the keyword `[ci skip]` in the commit message.

It is working but still add a pipeline skipped in the history:

[image]

Is there another way to skip the pipeline after a push in a pipeline run without seeing this skipped pipeline?

Comment: what is blocked by the skipped pipeline history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this skipped pipeline can not be hidden, the only solution is to run use workflow only when pipeline is triggered manually or from pipeline, but it will block any commit to create pipeline.

There is an open change for this: [gitlab#28369](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28369)